# PowerShell - Delete item from array

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell

I have an array (`$arr`) that contains:

```
A STRING -->       $arr[0]
*empty space* -->  $arr[1]
ANOTHER STRING --> $arr[2]
*empty space* -->  $arr[3]
LAST STRING -->    $arr[4]
```

And i would like to delete `$arr[1]` and `$arr[3]`. How can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several answers to this question, if `$arr` is a `System.Array` you would have to reconstruct it in order to remove the empty spaces. This is because this type is of a **fixed size**.

Some examples of how you could do that would be:

```
PS /> $arr = @(
    'A STRING'
    ' '
    'ANOTHER STRING'
    ' '
    'LAST STRING'
)

# Some examples:
$arr = $arr | Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) }
# OR
$arr = $arr.Where({ ' ' -ne $_ })
# OR
filter RemoveWhiteSpace {
    if(-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)){ $_ }
}

$arr = $arr | RemoveWhiteSpace
# And more...

PS /> $arr
A STRING
ANOTHER STRING
LAST STRING
```

**Note**, `Where-Object` is not the most efficient way of reconstructing the array but works fine for this example. If the array was much bigger, the most efficient way of filtering the collection would be:

```
PS /> $arr = @(
    'A STRING'
    ' '
    'ANOTHER STRING'
    ' '
    'LAST STRING'
)

$newArr = foreach($i in $arr)
{
    if(-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($i))
    {
        $i
    }
}

PS /> $newArr
A STRING
ANOTHER STRING
LAST STRING
```

Supposing, `$arr` is of a dynamic type that allows addition and removal of elements, you could do it like this:

```
PS /> $arr = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@(
    'A STRING'
    ' '
    'ANOTHER STRING'
    ' '
    'LAST STRING'
)

$arr.RemoveAt('1') # Removes position 1, in turn 
$arr.RemoveAt('2') # 'ANOTHER STRING' is the new position 1

PS /> $arr
A STRING
ANOTHER STRING
LAST STRING
```

Or like this:

```
PS /> $arr = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@(
    'A STRING'
    ' '
    'ANOTHER STRING'
    ' '
    'LAST STRING'
)

$arr.Remove(' ')
$arr.Remove(' ')

PS /> $arr
A STRING
ANOTHER STRING
LAST STRING
```

You can find a lot more information on [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: @AbrahamZinala sure, I see the edit now :)

Answer (score 2):

[Santiago's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68050381/712649) already solves the real problem her (removing the *empty* entries from your array), so I'll attempt to provide a dogmatic answer to the question "How can I remove the array items at index X and Y" instead:

PowerShell's index expression syntax allows you to *slice* arrays/list - pass an array of indices to the `[]` operator and it returns a new array consisting of the items at those indices:

```
PS ~> $arr = 'a,,b,,c' -split ','
PS ~> $arr[0..4]
a

b

c
```

That means we can exclude `$arr[1]` and `$arr[3]` by passing all possible index values *except* for `1` and `3`:

```
PS ~> $arr[@(0..($arr.Length - 1)).Where({$_ -notin 1,3})]
a
b
c
```

So the solution is to assign to `$arr` a slice of itself that excludes the desired indices:

```
$arr = $arr[@(0..($arr.Length - 1)).Where({$_ -notin 1,3})]
```

Comment: I've been wondering, is `[@(0..($arr.Length - 1)]` our go to for what in python would be `[:-1]`? Why don't we have `[0..-1]`? :(